# Audio pitch analysis

Tags: c#, audio, frequency, naudio, pitch-tracking

I'm very new to sound analysis in fact doing it for the first time all I need to do is to analyse an mp3 file or any other format and detect as pitch varies. simply I want to trim audio file where high notes occur.

[sound wave](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?safe=off&espv=210&es_sm=93&biw=1280&bih=701&tbm=isch&tbnid=bG7yHxHz1gVYhM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.hatcenter.amu.edu.pl/en/2012/08/sound-ecology/&docid=s3ohrx4y6clkLM&imgurl=http://www.hatcenter.amu.edu.pl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/SoundWaveForm1.jpg&w=1264&h=1200&ei=5kLFUo-0OonL2gXb6YGoAw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:11,s:0,i:129&iact=rc&page=2&tbnh=173&tbnw=182&start=10&ndsp=20&tx=136&ty=53)

I've tried NAudio and few articles but of no avail so if someone guides me in right direction for some tutorial and what API to use.

Answer (score 4):

1. The first you must know is [how the pitch is related to waveform](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/u11l2a.cfm).
2. Notice: simple single-channel waveform is represented by simple `byte` array. It consists of **[RIFF header](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) with some necessary parameters** and the wave sequence itself. More complicated waveforms (multichannel, high bit rate) are represented in some other way (`int` instead of `byte` array, interference and so on).
3. SO: In order to manipulate audio pitch, you have to learn how waveform is made (*step 2*) and write (or google) a certain algorithm, which will operate with a waveform's pitch in a way mentioned in *step 1*.

If you are very new to audio programming, there is a great beginner tutorial: [generating constant waveforms with C#](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Generating-Sound-Waves-with-C-Wave-Oscillators).

Comment: Sure looking into it. but it seems very theoretical I was looking for some jump start tutorial. thanks though

Comment: @user2987214 Added some info to answer, check it

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170394/fast-fourier-transform-in-c-sharp) to get the spectrum of the recording. By checking the spectrum for specific frequencies you could decide which parts of the audio contain high pitches.

Some theory:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram

Some resources:

- [How to perform the FFT to a wave-file using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479406/how-to-perform-the-fft-to-a-wave-file-using-naudio)
- https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/257586
- http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/242989

Answer (score 0):

Try a C# binding to Aubio

> aubio is a tool designed for the extraction of annotations from audio signals. Its features include segmenting a sound file before each of its attacks, performing pitch detection, tapping the beat and producing midi streams from live audio.

http://aubio.org/